# Managing Customer's UX expectations

Tags: usability, client, requirements

Is there any good theory about it? What elements should one consider?

User Interface / Cognition / Latency / Anything else?

Is it only on the side of Non-Functional Requirements? or it lives also in the Functional Requirements side?

Comment: Are you looking for the introduction to the theory of customer expectations, customer education, User experience, or how to derive it from the requirements?  You may also want to split this into multiple questions.

Comment: Although I am not convinced that the multitude of questions contained within are the best format for the site, I'll attempt to answer the Title question:

> How does one managing the customer's UX expectations?

By developing a [Paper Prototype][1] and/or doing [Hallway Usability Testing][2]. Generally showing the client at least three variations and getting their opinion as to direction.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_prototyping
  [2]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability_testing#Hallway_testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that articulating the goals of the UX upfront,  agreeing on measurements and goals helps a lot. What is the business case of the UX? How does the business track success? What parts of the experience most critically contribute to this success? 
What those are really is a case by case basis.

Answer (score 1):

I guess customer UX expectations are much more about politics and rhetorics than about UX itself.

Personally, I prefer a data-driven approach where one backs up the claims either by statistics or (perhaps informal but representative) user tests.

I do like models and I do like cognitive models, but as arguments, it seems people - esp. customers - tend to handle them roughly equal to opinions and rule of thumbs, and they're often applied in wrong contexts.